# Задача о сумме чисел, разделенных на группы запятыми

Tags: java, алгоритм, строки, int

Подскажите алгоритм решения задачи.
Заданы два целых числа `A` и `B` в необычном представлении: числа разделены на группы по 3 цифры, начиная с разряда единиц, запятыми. Ваша задача найти их сумму и вывести результат в обычной нормальной десятичной форме вывода.

**Input format**

Входные данные состоят из нескольких наборов данных. Каждый тестовый пример представлен в отдельной строке, содержит 2 целых числа `A` и `B` (`|A|`, `|B| ≤ 10^9`) и числа разделены пробелом.

**Output format**

Выходные данные для каждого тестового примера должны содержать результат в отдельной строке в нормальной форме вывода.

***Examples***

**Input**

1,234 2,345,678

-234,567,890 123,456,780

**Output**

2346912

-111111110

Решил с помощью использования строк, но программа проходит только 2 теста из 11. Подскажите какие еще есть варианты решения.
Всем спасибо.

Свой код:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

/*****************************************************************************/
public class Task {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        String s = in.nextLine();
        if(s.contains(" ")) {
            int n = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(0, s.indexOf(' ')).replace(",",""));
            int n1 = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(s.indexOf(' ')+1, s.length()).replace(",",""));
            System.out.println(n+n1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: А есть ограничения на длину чисел? Как там в Java с длинной арифметикой?

Comment: Даже, если поменять тип с int на long ничего не поменяется (

Comment: @Sergei у вас проблема в том, что у вас выводит результат только для первого тестового случая. а для второго ( как в примере - это не 2 разных запуска, это один запуск с 2 тестовыми кейсами) не выводит результат

Comment: На С++ на ура - `int main()
{
    string a,b;
    while(cin >> a >> b)
    {
        a.erase(remove(a.begin(),a.end(),','),a.end());
        b.erase(remove(b.begin(),b.end(),','),b.end());
        cout << stoi(a)+stoi(b) << endl;
    }
}`

Comment: @AndrewBystrov то есть нужно сделать проверку на символ конца строки? Только до какого момента мне тогда продолжать ввод тестов? До нажатия Enter или другой клаваши?

Comment: @AndrewBystrov спасибо за подсказку! неправильно понял условие. Получилось вот так:
`public class Task{
public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s = "";
        while (in.hasNext()) {
            s = in.nextLine();
            if (s.contains(" ")) {
                long n = Long.parseLong(s.substring(0, s.indexOf(' ')).replace(",", ""));
                long n1 = Long.parseLong(s.substring(s.indexOf(' ') + 1, s.length()).replace(",", ""));
                System.out.println(n + n1);
            }
        }
    }
}
`

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

/*****************************************************************************/
public class Task {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        String s = "";

        while (in.hasNext()) {
            s = in.nextLine();
            if (s.contains(" ")) {
                long n = Long.parseLong(s.substring(0, s.indexOf(' ')).replace(",", ""));
                long n1 = Long.parseLong(s.substring(s.indexOf(' ') + 1, s.length()).replace(",", ""));

                System.out.println(n + n1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```